# What exactly is HANDLE, LPCVOID and LPVOID in winapi? (specific to ReadProcessMemory)

Tags: c++, winapi

Here's the code that I've been looking at:

```
BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory(
  _In_  HANDLE  hProcess,
  _In_  LPCVOID lpBaseAddress,
  _Out_ LPVOID  lpBuffer,
  _In_  SIZE_T  nSize,
  _Out_ SIZE_T  *lpNumberOfBytesRead
);
```

Comment: You can find them in `winnt.h`. For example, `HANDLE` is typically a typedef for `PVOID` and `PVOID` is a typedef for `void*`.

Comment: They are `typedef`s going back to 16 bit Windows, so code compiles correctly on 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.  You should use them in your code (and not the underlying types) to future proof (as much as is possible) what you write.  Most are listed here: [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)

Comment: @ric The real reason why those are `typedef`s is so that the OS can specify its ABI. This indirection is common for libraries that provide an ABI (few do, so this confuses lots of clients).

Answer (score 4):

- `HANDLE` is a Windows NT handle.

  A handle is a numeric value assigned by the Windows kernel. Each handle is associated with an object and a set of permissions to that object. For example, it may be a handle to an open file (file object) and may give read access or read-write access. Each process has a list of handles maintained by the kernel. If the process attempts to use a handle which is not in that process' handle table, the call will fail.

  In this case it is a handle to a process object. You may obtain this handle using `OpenProcess`, `CreateProcesss`, or `DuplicateHandle`, or you may get it by inheritance when the process starts.

  If you get the handle by inheritance then the numeric value of the handle will be the same as it was in the parent process, so you can communicate that value on the command line or in the environment.
- `LPCVOID` is a memory address. The `C` indicates that the memory is constant, that is the function may read to the address but not write to it.

  In the case of `ReadProcessMemory` this is an address in the target process. Since you can't access this from the calling process, effectively it is just a number. However it is typed as a pointer to enable you to do pointer arithmetic on it, in order to more easily calculate other addresses in the target process.
- `LPVOID` is a memory address. Because it is not constant, the function may write to it.

  In this case this is the address within the calling process where the data will be written.

For a bonus:

- `_In_` indicates that the memory pointed to will be used by the function, but not changed.
- `_Out_` indicates that the memory will be written to by the function, but ***not*** read, therefore the contents of the memory before calling the function doesn't matter.
- There is also `_InOut_` which indicates that the argument may be used by the function and also changed by the function.
- See [SAL Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations?view=msvc-160) for more details.